# Задача с e-olymp #8380

Tags: c++, алгоритм

*Задача:*

В Баку вскоре откроется новая станция метро. Эскалатор в метро состоит из n ступенек, пронумерованных целыми числами от 1 до n. На ступеньках с номерами, кратными десяти, а также на первой и последней ступеньке, пишут их номера. При записи номера на каждую записанную цифру уходит одно и то же количество краски.

Чтобы рассчитать необходимое количество краски, требуется узнать, сколько цифр будет написано. Напишите программу, которая определяет, сколько всего цифр будет использовано в номерах подписанных ступенек.

*Входные данные:*

> Одно целое число n (1 ≤ n ≤ 10^18) - количество ступеней эскалатора.

*Выходные данные:*

> Выведите суммарное количество цифр в номерах подписанных ступенек.

Необходимо решить только с помощью формул и функций (не используя условные операторы, циклы и т.д.)

---

Вот наброски кода, где вычислил количество чисел для покраски и количество цифр в конечном числе, есть много идей, но все они без циклов в моем понимании не реализуются.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    long long n;
    long double num, numz;
    cin >> n;
    num = ceil(n / 10.0);
    numz = ceil(log10(n));
    return 0;
}
```

Проблема в том, что не могу понять как без цикла учесть то, что количество цифр в числе меняется каждый разряд и посчитать их сумму. Буду благодарен за любую помощь и подсказки.

Comment: `n / 10.0` - характерный случай бомбы неявных преобразований. Дело в том, что `double` может без потерь хранить целые числа только до 2^53, а `n` может быть больше. А вообще сумма цифр считается легко, достаточно сделать поразрядную табличку.

Comment: @VTT спасибо, а можно поподробнее про разрядную таблицу? Как ее реализовать в коде используя только формулы и функции?